# Strange issue trying fade on arduino on multiple LEDs

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to test out Fade on multiple LEDs on an Arduino Uno.  Here's the code i have written

```
int led[2] = {9,10};           // the pin that the LED is attached to
int brightness[2] = {0,0};    // how bright the LED is
int fadeAmount[2] = {5,15};    // how many points to fade the LED by
long previousMillis[2] = {0,0};        // will store last time LED was updated

long interval[2] = {30, 50};
// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup()  { 
  // declare pin 9 to be an output:
   pinMode(led[0], OUTPUT);
   pinMode(led[1], OUTPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
 } 

 // the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
 void loop()  { 
   // set the brightness of pins:

   for (int counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++) {
     unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

     analogWrite(led[counter], brightness[counter]);
     Serial.print("LED ");
     Serial.print(led[counter]);
     Serial.print(": Brightness ");
     Serial.println(brightness[counter]);    

     if (currentMillis - previousMillis[counter] > interval[counter]) {
       // change the brightness for next time through the loop:
       brightness[counter] = brightness[counter] + fadeAmount[counter];

       // reverse the direction of the fading at the ends of the fade: 
       if (brightness[counter] == 0 || brightness[counter] == 255) {
         fadeAmount[counter] = -fadeAmount[counter] ; 
       }     
     }                         
   }
 }
```

Here's the weird thing.  If i comment out the Serial stuff (print and begin), the fades don't work.  They just "flicker" a little.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: The code is too fast?, try to add a sleep instead of print statements and see how it works... but you are probably doing transitions too fast for your eye.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It looks like I forgot a line of code.

```
  previousMillis[counter] = currentMillis;
```

I should have put that in on the first if statement in the code.  I guess the act of observing by using the serial print slowed things down enough that the code seemed to work.

Boy, do i feel foolish.